# What preparations should I have to fly from the US to Mexico?

Tags: faa-regulations, international

I am holding a US private pilot certificate with instrument rating, and planning to fly a single-engine aircraft from US to Mexico.

Regarding legal, visa, airspace/ATC knowledge requirements, flight plan filing, what do I need to prepare and how may I find the materials (in English).

Comment: Much of this is covered here: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/306/69

Comment: More importantly, where are resources to find the charts and frequencies of service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AOPA has a guide [here](http://www.aopa.org/Flight-Planning/Mexico). I think it should cover most of your points apart from visa/immigration, because that isn't really an aviation issue (unless perhaps you're commercial air crew using a flight crew visa). Don't forget to plan ahead for re-entering the US, there are a bunch of requirements for that too, including using [eAPIS](https://eapis.cbp.dhs.gov).

Some points from the guide are:

- Documentation: you need a radio license for the pilot and the aircraft
- Insurance: add Mexico to your insurance policy if it isn't already covered
- Flight plan: you must be on an IFR or defense VFR flight plan to cross the [ADIZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Defense_Identification_Zone)
- Night VFR isn't allowed in Mexico (with a few exceptions for flights to the US)
- It looks like the more paperwork you have with you, the better
- FBO services are likely to be more limited than in the US, and fees are often higher

Also check out the [Caribbean Sky Tours Pilots Association](http://www.caribbeanskytours.com/), they publish a [pilots' guide](http://www.caribbeanskytours.com/pilot_guide.html) to Mexico and Central America.